# SQL column value null, search filter mistaken

Tags: mysql, sql

Given two users,

```
NAME   | JOB     | CITY
John   | null    | Washington D.C.
Sandy  | gardener| Nashville
```

If my SQL query reads:

```
 "SELECT * FROM users WHERE job != 'gardener'",
```

my results are 0,

where I would like them to be 1:

```
John |  null  | Washington  D.C.
```

This is a much simpler example of a larger query I'm trying to make. If I default Job to '0', I get the correct results, but I'd rather have a null in there, for the sake of the rest of the application.

UPDATE: Thanks for all of the suggestions, but I face another problem.

Let's say my SQL query is:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE city != Washington D.C. and job != 'gardener' OR job IS NULL"
```

Unfortunately, this returns John, whereas I don't want John because he lives in Washington D.C. I want to return 0 rows in this case.

Comment: There is no column called gardener !?!?!?

Comment: The astute use of parentheses will fix that.

Comment: Your updated query isn't evaluating the way you expect.  `AND` conditions are evaluated before `OR` conditions; your query gets everybody who [`does not live in DC`, `has a job that is not gardener`] `OR` [`has no job`].  Whenever you add `OR` conditions to a query, always put parentheses to be clear - and to get the correct meaning.  Also, to prevent future data duplication problems, you probably want to create tables `job` and `city` that you refer to by fk.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse mind showing where you would put the parentheses so that we return everyone who doesn't live in dc and who isn't a gardener, aka no one?

Comment: Well there's only two choices, right?

Comment: Think about it this way - your city condition is essentially unrelated to the job condition; it's _another_ condition, yes, but it doesn't really matter to the job one.  You're trying to change the order of operations from "default" (`AND` first)...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Ok I think you mean this: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE city != Washington D.C. and (job != 'gardener' OR job IS NULL)"

Comment: and we have a winner :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name,job,city
FROM users
WHERE IFNULL(job,'') != 'gardener';
```

if you wanted to use `OR job IS NULL` in your updated query, as Strawberry mentioned, you must put parenthesis around your JOB conditions like below

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE city != 'Washington D.C.' and (job != 'gardener' OR job IS NULL)
```

Comment: this is perfect because it takes care of the condition where a row with a null value also fails to satisfy another WHERE clause condition, that row is not returned

Comment: you can still use your updated query and make it work with parenthesis around your `job` check conditions. See bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE job != 'gardener' OR job IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to do I get rid of a row with a null value that also violates some other condition of the where clause? See my update

Comment: it seems Tin Tran's answer takes care of it

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE
  job != 'gardener' or job is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL means the absence of data, so technically SQL doesn't 'know' if the field where the value is NULL ! = 'gardener', that is why you als need to check IS NULL as mentioned above.